# How to list value for an individual when another column is equal to a particular value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data set:

```
structure(list(Month = c("January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January"), Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Day = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), Name = c("Joe", "Mike", "Will ", "Eric", "Joe", 
"Mike", "Will ", "Eric", "Joe", "Mike", "Will ", "Eric"), Y = c(3.2, 
3.4, 5.5, 6.8, 1.3, 1.2, 4.9, 5, 3.3, 7.2, 7.7, 3.9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a new column ('Day2Y') that identifies the Y value for each person ('name') when Day is equal to 2 (for any particular week). So I would like the above table to become this:

```
structure(list(Month = c("January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January"), Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Day = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), Name = c("Joe", "Mike", "Will ", "Eric", "Joe", 
"Mike", "Will ", "Eric", "Joe", "Mike", "Will ", "Eric"), Y = c(3.2, 
3.4, 5.5, 6.8, 1.3, 1.2, 4.9, 5, 3.3, 7.2, 7.7, 3.9), Day2Y = c(3.2, 
3.4, 5.5, 6.8, 3.2, 3.4, 5.5, 6.8, 3.3, 7.2, 7.7, 3.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

It's important to note that Day is not a unique identifier, so I'm guessing I need to group_by month and week perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `Name`, `Month` and `Week` and extract the `Y` value where `Day == 2`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Name, Month, Week) %>% mutate(Day2Y = Y[Day == 2])

#   Month    Week   Day Name        Y Day2Y
#   <chr>   <int> <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 January     1     2 "Joe"     3.2   3.2
# 2 January     1     2 "Mike"    3.4   3.4
# 3 January     1     2 "Will "   5.5   5.5
# 4 January     1     2 "Eric"    6.8   6.8
# 5 January     1     3 "Joe"     1.3   3.2
# 6 January     1     3 "Mike"    1.2   3.4
# 7 January     1     3 "Will "   4.9   5.5
# 8 January     1     3 "Eric"    5     6.8
# 9 January     2     2 "Joe"     3.3   3.3
#10 January     2     2 "Mike"    7.2   7.2
#11 January     2     2 "Will "   7.7   7.7
#12 January     2     2 "Eric"    3.9   3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Day2Y := Y[match(2, Day)], .(Name, Month, Week)]
```